# Extract portion of text with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I would like to extract lines in between `'*Node\n'` and `'*Element, type=S4R\n'` from the following text using regex.

```
text ="""**
*Part, name=Part-2
*Node
      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75
      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75
   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007
*Element, type=S4R
 1,   1,  21, 357,  46
 2,  21,  22, 358, 357
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet24, internal, generate
    1,  1416,     1
**"""
```

I have tried `re.findall(r"\*Node\s([\s\S]+)\*\w", text)` and `re.findall(r"(?<=\*Node\s)([\s\S]+)(?=\*)", text)` but not able to filter out the end portion of the text. I'm getting output:

```
['      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75\n      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75\n   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007\n*Element, type=S4R\n 1,   1,  21, 357,  46\n 2,  21,  22, 358, 357\n*Nset, nset=_PickedSet24, internal, generate\n    1,  1416,     1\n*']
```

However, if I try  `re.findall(r"(?<=name\s)([\s\S]+)(?=\selon)", text1)` & `re.findall(r"name\s([\s\S]+)\selon", text1)` for the following code, I do get `['isn,t']` as desired.

`text1 = """my name isn,t\nelon *nestla"""`

**EDIT**
full text is the following, there are multiple such patches to extract and I can end the patches with *Element always

```
text = """** PARTS
**
*Part, name=Part-2
*Node
      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75
      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75
   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007
*Element, type=S4R
 1,   1,  21, 357,  46
 2,  21,  22, 358, 357
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet24, internal, generate
    1,  1416,     1
*End Part
**  
*Part, name=plate#Part-1
*Node
      1, -0.449999988, -0.477499992,           0.
      2, -0.400000006, -0.477499992,           0.
    121, 0.0500000007, 0.0225000009,           0.
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet2, internal, generate
   1,  121,    1
*End Part
**  
**"""
```

Comment: Why not like this? `\*Node\r?\n([\s\S]+)\r?\n\*Element, type=S4R` https://regex101.com/r/ilpWYk/1

Comment: You could get multiple matches like this `regex = r"^\*Node\r?\n((?:(?!\*\w).*\r?\n)*)\*\w.*"` and then use re.findall. See https://ideone.com/DFel7r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be more specific and add the newlines and match `\*Element, type=S4R` after it.

```
\*Node\r?\n([\s\S]+?)\r?\n\*Element, type=S4R
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dqtP46/1)

Without unnecessary backtracking you could also start the match with `*Node` and match all lines that do not start with `*Element` using a negative lookahead.

```
^\*Node\r?\n((?:(?!\*Element).*\r?\n)*)\*Element, type=S4R
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vIqSgn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3bSorA)

```
import re

regex = r"^\*Node\r?\n((?:(?!\*Element).*\r?\n)*)\*Element, type=S4R"
text = ("**\n"
    "*Part, name=Part-2\n"
    "*Node\n"
    "      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75\n"
    "      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75\n"
    "   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007\n"
    "*Element, type=S4R\n"
    " 1,   1,  21, 357,  46\n"
    " 2,  21,  22, 358, 357\n"
    "*Nset, nset=_PickedSet24, internal, generate\n"
    "    1,  1416,     1\n"
    "**")

matches = re.search(regex, text, re.MULTILINE)
if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
```

Output

```
      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75
      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75
   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007
```

---

If you want to find all the matches, you could also use [re.findall](https://ideone.com/DFel7r) and end the match with `*`, a word character `\w` and match the rest of the line using `.*`

```
import re
 
regex = r"^\*Node\r?\n((?:(?!\*\w).*\r?\n)*)\*\w.*"
text = """** PARTS
**
*Part, name=Part-2
*Node
      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75
      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75
   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007
*Element, type=S4R
 1,   1,  21, 357,  46
 2,  21,  22, 358, 357
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet24, internal, generate
    1,  1416,     1
*End Part
**  
*Part, name=plate#Part-1
*Node
      1, -0.449999988, -0.477499992,           0.
      2, -0.400000006, -0.477499992,           0.
    121, 0.0500000007, 0.0225000009,           0.
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet2, internal, generate
   1,  121,    1
*End Part
**  
**""" 
 
print(re.findall(regex, text, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75\n      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75\n   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007\n', '      1, -0.449999988, -0.477499992,           0.\n      2, -0.400000006, -0.477499992,           0.\n    121, 0.0500000007, 0.0225000009,           0.\n']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please see, I have updated the full text.

Comment: @hovedguy I have updated the answer. Should it always start with `*Node` and end with `*`? How many matches do you expect?

Comment: Yes, that's right. There are 3 to 4  matches. Thanks again :)

Comment: @hovedguy Like this? `^\*\w.*\r?\n((?:(?!\*\w).*\r?\n)*)(?=\*\w)` See https://regex101.com/r/Q9F05G/1

Comment: It works fine, the best part is the interactive regex link you shared. It is very helpful and now I can try out other stuff there. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

text ="""**
*Part, name=Part-2
*Node
      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75
      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75
   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007
*Element, type=S4R
 1,   1,  21, 357,  46
 2,  21,  22, 358, 357
*Nset, nset=_PickedSet24, internal, generate
    1,  1416,     1
**"""

print( re.search(r'^\*Node(.*?)^\*Element, type=S4R', text, flags=re.S|re.M).group(1) )
```

Prints:

```
      1,         0.25,          0.5,         0.75
      2,         0.25,           0.,         0.75
   1416,  0.200000003,           0., 0.0500000007
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please see, I have updated the full text.